# git is not adding project files other than .gitignore

Tags: git

For some reason, my local git will not add files other than .gitignore

I even created a blank directory with an empty .gitignore file and another test.txt file and it will only add the .gitignore

**Is this a configuration issue that I screwed up? How do I fix it?**

I run `git add .` then `git commit -m "test"` and I get back:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

and the test.txt does not appear

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
```

yields:

```
100644 blob 4fa9688faea285415faa1d92e2975c02c6e98fb1    .gitignore
```

but I definately have a text.txt in there

**UPDATE:**

I added `!*.txt` to my .gitignore file and then it added the txt file. Why would I have to explicitly add all included files?

Comment: what do you see when you do `git config --global core.excludesfile`

Comment: also, what does git status results in?

Comment: `git config --global core.excludesfile` returned nothing.

Comment: `git status` yielded `On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: so you have nothing to commit, Either check git log to see if you have committed something already or make a change in the file and then check git status. It should show your change, then try git commit -am "your meesage"

Comment: could you share your complete `.gitignore` as well

Comment: also try using the `git check-ignore [path]`

Comment: `!*.txt` is now the only thing in my .gitignore file. before I added that line, test.txt would not `git add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had an .gitignore file in a parent directory which precipitated to the child project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete all of the upstream `.gitignore` files.